# Stage is showing to be null in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

This method(abc) is called when a button is pressed in the first scene. What it does is it changes the scene to waitingScreen and calls another method waitscr()

```
 public void abc(ActionEvent event)throws Exception{
 stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    //for changing the scene.
    Parent administrator = 
    FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("waitingScreen.fxml"));
    stage.setScene(new Scene(administrator));
    stage.show();
    conn.close();
     waiting_screen_Controller c = new waiting_screen_Controller();
     c.waitscr(event);
```

What waitscr does is it starts a timer for 5 seconds and when the timer ends 
it calls another method setscr() (maybe i could have started the timer in abc only)

```
  public void waitscr(ActionEvent event)throws IOException{
    timetask = new TimerTask(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(!timing){
                try{
                    timetask.cancel();
                    setscr(event);
                }
                catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
               }
            }
            else
                timing = updateTime();
        }
    };
     timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timetask,1000,1000);
}
```

it updates the time

```
 public boolean updateTime(){
    System.out.println(s);
       if(s==0){
           return false;
        }
        s--;
        return true;
        }
```

what setscr does is it  changes the scene back to the first one..

```
  public void setscr(ActionEvent event)throws IOException{ 
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("first.fxml"));
        Parent parent = loader.load();
        Scene s=new Scene(parent);
        stage = (Stage)((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        System.out.print(event.getSource());
        stage.setScene(s);
        stage.show();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

    }
```

But the problem is it gives npe in stage.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sample.waiting_screen_Controller.setscr(waiting_screen_Controller.java:106)
at sample.waiting_screen_Controller$1.run(waiting_screen_Controller.java:45)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I thought this was because of ActionEvent because npe is at stage but i printed the source of ActionEvent and it is not null.

Comment: Which line is line 106? And why don’t you pass the stage to the other methods, instead of passing the event?

Comment: but being curious why it was giving error in above code??

Comment: Don't know, without knowing which line was throwing the exception and which value is null.

Comment: @Dbuiss, i presume it is giving you npe because the running is asyncronous so the reference is lost between execution, try passing it around

Comment: Another nice question ... and welcome to upvote levels btw ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're replacing the scene before calling `waitscr`. This way when you call `Scene.getWindow` the scene is no longer associated with a window and the result is `null`.

You shouldn't do this from a non-application thread anyways.

By retrieving the window only once and using a `Platform.runLater` you should be able to fix this issue:

```
public void abc(ActionEvent event)throws Exception{
    stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    ...
    c.waitscr(stage);
```

```
public void waitscr(final Stage stage) throws IOException {
    timetask = new TimerTask(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(!timing){
                try{
                    timetask.cancel();
                    setscr(stage);
                } catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else
                timing = updateTime();
        }
    };
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timetask,1000,1000);
}
```

```
public void setscr(Stage stage)throws IOException{
        // there seems to be a try missing somewhere
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("first.fxml"));
        Parent parent = loader.load();
        Scene s=new Scene(parent);

        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            // scene update on javafx application thread
            stage.setScene(s);
            stage.show();
        });

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: when i am setting label in public void run() in the timer in the else part it is giving npe. please help. i have double checked the id of the label in the fxml and i have written the annotation @fxml also.